# What's wrong with this code, It's crashing

Tags: c++, stdvector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector < long long > arr;
    arr[0] = 1;
    arr[1] = 2;
    long long sum = 0;
    int i = 2;  

    do
    {
        arr[i] = arr[i - 1] + arr[i - 2];
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 0)
            sum += arr[i];
        ++i;
    } while (arr[i] < 4000000);

    cout << sum << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Just using a vector and long long as object type. Prints nothing and crashes. Why? Do I need to resize the array, or problem is something else. Please help me.

Comment: Yes, you need to either `resize` your vector, initialize it with a size, or `push_back` into it. Note that (supposing elements are zeroed) your `while` condition will always be true as you are testing an element which has not yet been initialized.

Comment: The array is initially empty, and you do not resize it before you access individual elements, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: You should init the vector with a certain size (vector < long long > arr(2);) or push_back the elements. arr.push_back(1); arr.push_back(2);

Comment: Doesn't need to be `long long` by the way...

Answer (score 1):

`vector < long long > arr;` doesn't allocate any space for your variables. It just declares a vector. Either use `arr.resize(MAX_SIZE);`, where `MAX_SIZE` is some maximum value of `i` that you will never cross, or use `arr.push_back(...)` instead of `arr [ ... ] = ...`

Comment: Why should the maximum size be defined via a macro? (`MAX_SIZE` certainly looks like one.)

Comment: @ChristianHackl: I didn't say it should be; `MAX_SIZE` can be replaced for some number that the programmer deems to be the maximum size and can be replaced by a variable, a number, or anything else. That should be rather obvious from the wording...

Comment: In C++, ALL_CAPS usually signals a macro.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: I know; like I said, in this particular case, it should be incredibly obvious from context that you can replace it with a variable or number if you wish.

Comment: Plenty of code standards use all caps for constants, not (just) macros.  R_Kapp's example here is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Working version of your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector < long long > arr(2);
    arr[0] = 1;
    arr[1] = 2;
    long long sum = 0;
    int i = 1;

    do
    {
        ++i;
        arr.push_back(arr[i - 1] + arr[i - 2]);
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 0)
            sum += arr[i];
    } while (arr[i] < 4000000);

    cout << sum << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  vector < long long > arr;
>  arr [ 0 ] = 1;
>  arr [ 1 ] = 2;
> ```

You create an empty vector and then try to set its first and second element. The behaviour of your program is **undefined** as soon as `arr [ 0 ]` is hit. Crashes are only one possible result of this. Your program is allowed to do *anything*.

You must either initialise the vector to size 2 or add the elements after initialisation.

```
vector < long long > arr(2);
arr [ 0 ] = 1;
arr [ 1 ] = 2;
```

Or:

```
vector < long long > arr;
arr.push_back(1);
arr.push_back(2);
```

I recommend you review the chapter about `std::vector` in the book which you are reading. Your compiler probably also offers some way to enable run-time checks for standard containers to turn possible crashes into guaranteed ones.